# Use SetParent on project's own console, in a winforms panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, console, pinvoke

I'm trying to take advantage of the console project type's console to display output from my windows form.

Basically I have my project set to a console project type. I open a windows form from Main. On that windows form I have a panel in which I'd like to use `SetParent()` ([pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetParent.html)) that will contain the console.

Is this possible? I've even tried adding another console project to the solution and hosting THAT console project in the panel, but it goes invisible as soon as `SetParent()` is called. I've tried using `ShowWindow()` ([pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow)) to get it to be visible but nothing happens. How can I do this?

I've made a wrapper over these Win32 functions but I feel like they're pretty self explanatory. Here's the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Utilities.SetParent(Utilities.GetWindowHandle(ConsoleTitle), panel1.Handle);
        Utilities.SetWindowVisible(Utilities.GetWindowHandle(ConsoleTitle), true);
    }
```

`ConsoleTitle` is just a string set to my console's title, which is "Tester Console". For the record the console disappears when my code is called, so I know it's grabbing the window handle and doing *something*.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't think this will work out. Solve the problem a different way.